# Javascript manipulating only 1 component from multiple

Tags: javascript

I have a small javascript slider.

That changes the slides on click event on the radio buttons:

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('ul.slider');
sliders.forEach(slider => {
    const slides = slider.querySelectorAll('.figure');
    const controlls = slider.querySelectorAll('.controller');
    const slideshowSpeed = 2000;
    let currentSlide = 0;
    
    document.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
        if(e.target.getAttribute('name')=="controller")
            nextSlide(e.target.value);
    });
    
  
});
```

Now I have 2 components / sliders on my page and when I click the radio button of 1st slider the second one is also changed even though I put it inside a forEach, is there a better way to approach this?

I can't change the ids classes of slider as it's a dynamic website.

Please only vanilla JS answers, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be happening because you added an Event listener to `document`, meaning the events it listens to applies to the whole DOM tree. Any `oninput` call will trigger the event listener. Instead of adding it to the `document` object, I recommend you add it locally.

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll('ul.slider');

for (slider of sliders) {
    const slides = slider.querySelectorAll('.figure');
    const controlls = slider.querySelectorAll('.slider__controller__radio');
    const slideshowSpeed = 2000;
    const sliderControllers = slider.getElementsByName("slider_controller");
    let currentSlide = 0;

    for (controller of sliderControllers) {
        controller.addEventListener('input', (index) => {
            slides[currentSlide].className = 'figure';
            currentSlide = index % slides.length;
            controlls[currentSlide].checked=true;
            slides[currentSlide].className = 'figure visible';
        }, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now, but the radio buttons get unchecked from one slider when I click them on the other slider, any ideas on this?

Comment: That might be because they all have the same `name` attribute, meaning they are look at as options to choose from, so only one can be checked at any given time.